# FBSession open a new session with Page Access Token

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I have successfully obtained a valid **Page Access Token** (PAT) using `[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:parameters:HTTPMethod];` ( double checked with Access Token Debugger ).

The PAT contains the following permissions of my Facebook Page , which I am the Admin :

> create_note manage_pages photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream share_item status_update video_upload

*though I only requested `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` ...*

Now, I want to publish story **on behalf of the page** ( not "post by others" ). I use this code:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"http://www.google.com", @"link",
                  @"Test Name", @"name",
                  @"Test Message", @"message",
                  page_access_token, @"access_token",
                  nil];
 FBRequest *req = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"{MY_PAGE_ID}/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [req startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
    });
 }];
```

I am able to issue the post , but the post is issued as others, not the page admin. Therefore, I am thinking of creating a new `FBSession` with the PAT. Am I going to correct direction ? or did I miss something ?